# Composite Component Binding is resolves to null

Tags: jsf-2.2

I am trying to bind a composite component to an ajax listener but the bind variable resolves to null. If I use the bind variable as part of the body, eg. `#{bind}` it does resolve properly. I assume it is a bug, but would like a second opinion before I report it. Thanks

page:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
        xmlns:jstl="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:jfunc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions"
        xmlns:jid1="http://mydomain.com/facelets">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="commentBoxForm">
        <jid1:confirmModal title="t" cssID="a" binding="#{bind}">
            </jid1:confirmModal>

            <h:commandLink value="click">
                <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form"
                    listener="#{bind.getFamily()}" />
            </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

component:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
        xmlns:jstl="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:jfunc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/functions"
        xmlns:jid1="http://mydomain.com/facelets">

        <composite:interface>
            <composite:attribute name="cssID" required="true" />
            <composite:attribute name="title" required="true" />
        </composite:interface>

        <composite:implementation>

            <h:panelGroup >
                ......
            </h:panelGroup>

        </composite:implementation>
    </ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug. See [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2925) for details.

A composite component `binding` attribute will not work properly for Ajax calls.